# .click error on appended element, even with .on

Tags: jquery

I got an error when trying to use .click on a appended div-element, so I tried to use .on instead, but it didn't solve it. What is wrong with the last rows in this code?

The element .table is the frustrating one:

```
    $('#mapH').focusout(function(){
    var i = 0;
    while (i < $('#mapH').val()) {
        $('#mapCreator').append("<div class='row'></div>");

        var j = 0;
        while(j < $('#mapW').val()) {
            $('.row').last().append("<div class='table empty "+i+"-"+j+"'></div>");
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    $('.table').css("width", 100/$('#mapW').val()+"%");
    $('.row').css("height", $('.table').width());
})



$('.table').on("click", function(){
    //$('body').append("<div class='popup'></div>");
    alert('hej');
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be semicolons behind the closing round brackets?

Comment: What is the error? Please be more specific about your problem.

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: The alert('hej'); in the bottom of the code is not happening, when the element .table is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have extra space in class of table after empty. Change `class='table empty "` to `class='table empty"` and delegate event to parent of .table.empty or document.

```
$(document).on("click",'[class^=table]', function(){
    //$('body').append("<div class='popup'></div>");
    alert('hej');
});
```

Comment: if the spaces are removed like you suggest wouldn't that result in a classes like `empty0-0` ?  and then `.table.empty` would never match ?

Comment: i liked  the first selector (`.table.empty`) better because it does not depend on having `table`as beginning of `class` i just would have changed the class to something like this `class='table empty empty0-0` or `class='table empty cell0-0`

Comment: I do not really understand the purpose of messing with class='table empty 0-0' and editing it to class='table empty0-0', I tested it and it did not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
$("div .table").click(function(){

// code here 

alert("call");

});
```

Comment: if `$(".table").on("click", ...` does not work  then `$("div .table").on("click", ...` or `$("div .table").click(...` would also not work. because it uses a more specific selector.